# Slideshow disappearance after SUPEE-6788 patch

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-6788

After installing SUPEE-6788 my slideshow has gone, it's enabled and added to the content, nothing was change on that end. All I did was FTP the SUPEE-6788 patch.

I added 6482 & 6285 refreshing each time to make sure everything still worked, is this a known issue with extensions?

I was using Dolphin_Slideshow 1.0.3

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add your block permission

```
Go to Admin -> System -> Permissions -> Block -> Add new block
```

Add your block name and set value for Is Allowed to YES

For more details about patch 6788 check [this link.](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)

Comment: Thankyou very much!