# Displaying products in category code no longer working after SUPEE-6788 patch

Tags: magento-community, phtml, cms-block, supee-6788

We added the SUPEE-6788 patch and this code that we used to display products from a category no longer works:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no featured products') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <ul>
        <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(236,177); ?>" width="236" height="177" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

Any ideas what I need to change to make this work again?  We have this code in a .phtml file and call it on a CMS page using the following call:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="29" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This a common issue related to block permissions feature

Read this for more information [Slideshow disappearance after SUPEE-6788 patch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103145/slideshow-disappearance-after-supee-6788-patch?rq=1)